# Counting sort in Julia

Tags: julia, counting-sort

Can someone help me out? I got a code for *counting sort* in Julia but it seems that it does not work. It gives me the wrong output. The code is down below:

*NumEl* - Number of elements
*MArray* - Main Array
*minAr* - Minimal value in the array
*maxAr* - Maximum value in the array

```
     NumEl = 30
     MArray = Array{Int64}(undef, NumEl)  
     MArray .+= rand(1:100,length(MArray)) 
     println("Our random array with $NumEl is: $MArray")

 #Minimum and maximum element of the array
 minAr = MArray[1]
 maxAr = MArray[1]

println("--------------")

for i in 1:NumEl
    if  MArray[i] < minAr
          global minAr = MArray[i] 
    elseif MArray[i] > maxAr 
         global maxAr =  MArray[i]
    end
end

println("Max element in the array: $maxAr\n")
println("Minimal element in the array: $minAr\n")

Size = maxAr - minAr  + 1
Count = Array{Int64}(undef, Size + 1)

for i in 1:Size
    Count[i] = 0
end

j = 0
for i in 1:10
    Count[MArray[i] - minAr] = Count[MArray[i] - minAr ] + 1
end

z = 1
for i in minAr:maxAr
    for j in 1:Count[i+1-minAr]
        MArray[global z+=1] = i   
    end
end

println("--------------")

println("Our sorted array: $MArray")
```

Comment: Can you describe how the output is wrong? Maybe some samples will help here.

Comment: Input array: [19, 99, 6, 78, 90, 3, 39, 31, 9, 65, 77, 63, 80, 97, 57, 86, 60, 75, 22, 95, 11, 52, 28, 42, 24, 60, 1, 6, 93, 53]  --------------
Max element in the array: 99

Minimal element in the array: 1

--------------
Our sorted array: [19, 2, 5, 8, 18, 30, 38, 64, 77, 89, 98, 63, 80, 97, 57, 86, 60, 75, 22, 95, 11, 52, 28, 42, 24, 60, 1, 6, 93, 53]

Comment: Please edit the the post above and add this info there ^

Comment: What do you mean? What info

Comment: The input and output should be in the original question, ideally not the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 bugs I see, ignoring the global and style:

Lines 2:3 Adding a random value to an uninitiialized vector. Ouch, that can really throw the range of MArray off. Line 2 should be deleted and the results of `rand(1:100, NumEl)` assigned directly to `MArray` on line 3

Line 31: 1:10 should be 1:NumEl

Line 32: indexes are off by 1

Line 35: z is off by 1

The rest is left to the OP to correct.